# Vector data disappears after function exits

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a custom vector class called VEC and a class called Data that holds a std::vector of VECs called v. VEC acts as a very simple vector that just stores 4 values.

```
vector<VEC> v;
```

Elsewhere, I have two functions; process and create. My process() is supposed to accept a Data object as a parameter and then alter its contents. It is declared as

```
void myClass::process(Data data);
```

Inside this function, I create a temporary vector of VECs, then push it's contents into data's v:

```
VEC v1(1, 1, 1, 1);
VEC v2(2, 2, 2, 2);
VEC v3(3, 3, 3, 3);
vector<VEC> temp;
temp.push_back(v1);
temp.push_back(v2);
temp.push_back(v3);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    data.v.push_back(vtemp[i]);
  }
cout << data.v.size() << endl;
```

As you would expect, this prints out 3.

Now here's where the problem happens. The other function create() calls process() on every Data object in the vector datalist. For testing purposes, this one only uses the first element.

```
void myClass::create() {
    process(dataList[0]);
    cout << dataList[0].v.size() << endl;
  }
```

This is what it prints out

```
3
0
```

As you can see, it works properly in the process() function, but the v vector seems to empty itself as soon as that function exits. This is a problem, because I need each Data object to save it's new v contents after process() is called. What's going on here?

Comment: You seem to be operating on copy of `Data`. Take the argument by a reference if you intend to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate your `Data` object, your `process` function must be declared as such:

```
void myClass::process(Data& data);
```

You have to pass by reference, else a copy of `data` will be made when you pass it to the function. The ampersand (`&`) after `Data` in the above function prototype means "take a reference to a variable `data` of type `Data`."

The way you had it, any changes the function makes to `data` will be done **only** to this local variable. Thus, the changes will be destroyed when the `process` function exits.